# Roots of unity - solving $z^n = 1$ and $z^n = -1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If we are solving $z^n = 1$, the unique solutions are given by $e^{i\theta}  $ with $\theta$ being each of the angles you get when you split up $2\pi$ into $n$ angles (sorry for the bad wording - I didn't know how else to phrase it).

In a solution to a problem, the author solves $z^4 + 1 = 0$, and it is deduced that $z = e^{i\pi/4}, e^{3i\pi/4}, e^{5i\pi/4}, e^{7i\pi/4}$.

So is solving $z^n + 1 = 0$ equivalent to solving $z^n = 1$? And if so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $z^n+1=0$, then $z^{2n}=1$ but $z^n\neq1$. So, to take your example, you can solve $z^8=1$, then from those 8 solutions remove any that also appear as solutions to $z^4=1$. The four that remain are solutions to $z^4=-1$.